# If a formula φ contains at most one occurrence of any sentence letter, then φ is not a tautology

Tags: logic

If a formula φ contains at most one occurrence of any sentence letter, then φ is not a tautology. The only connectives in my system are → and ¬. I think I should attempt this by induction on the complexity of φ (the number of connectives). Then we have two cases to consider: either φ = ¬ψ, or φ = ψ→ξ, where ψ, ξ satisfy the induction hypothesis. I'm stuck here, as I cannot find a property of sentences that contain at most one occurence of any sentence letter to exploit.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to prove "If a formula φ contains at most one occurrence of any sentence letter, then φ is not a tautology nor a contradiction" by a pretty straightforward induction as you indicate.

Comment: What makes you think this is correct? Surely, the formula A → (B → B) is a tautology despite containing only one instance of the sentence letter A? Or do you have other restrictions in mind?

Comment: @Bumble - "at most one occurrence of **any** sentence letter".

Comment: You have to start the induction with the *base* case, i.e. *atomic* formulae. An atomic formula is made of one single sentence letetr, and it is not a tautology. Thus, for the *induction* step, the case of *negeation* is traightforward : if ψ is not a taut, neither φ = ¬ψ is. It remains the case φ = ψ→ξ.

Comment: See the full answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636668/if-a-formula-%cf%86-contains-at-most-one-occurrence-of-any-sentence-letter-then-%cf%86).

Comment: This is a question in mathematical logic, and it belongs on Math SE.